# defaulting away from js on hrefs

Tags: javascript

I want to use this page scrolling technique from js.

http://www.xfunda.com/index.php?view=article&id=55%3Ajavascript-page-scroll-scroll-a-web-page-from-bottom-to-top-smoothly&option=com_content&Itemid=75

But what if the user doesnt have js

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goto_top()"><img src="/goto_top.gif" alt="Top" border="0" /></a></p>
```

but what if I want to just user the anchors ont he page for a user who doesnt have js turned on for the nice scrolling effect?

Answer (score 1):

To use anchors, change `javascript:void(0)` to `#anchor_name` and make sure that `goto_top()` or whatever your click handler is returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The key way to implement that is to use the anchors #top within the hyperlink, and if the user has javascript enabled, then you use JS code to modify the link.  That's the unobtrusive javascript approach.

```
var element = document.getElementById("alink");
element.href = "javascript:void(0);"; //changes from #top
element.onclick = function() { goto_top(); };
```

That way, if JS is disabled, the #top reference stays in the link, but if JS is enabled, it will replace and use the nice scrolling effect.